# Angular2 - Uncaught ReferenceError: onInputChange is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: angular, angular-material

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onInputChange is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange

I am looking at the code...,my lord the function exists.  And yet I get the above?  WOW..why? I just want to fire an event if html changes in input

```xml
<input mdInput [formControlName]="i" onchange="onInputChange()"
```

```js
onInputChange(){

    console.log('DUDE');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding to the event

```
<input mdInput [formControlName]="i" (change)="onInputChange()"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input mdInput [formControlName]="i" (change)="onInputChange()"

onInputChange(){

    console.log('DUDE');
}
```

Also, as its seems you are using model driven form, you can also do that :

```
this.yourForm.get('i').valueChanges
    .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    })
```